# ImageView onClick() and fling() gesture clashing

Tags: android, android-gesture

I have an activity in which i have set an imageView. OnFling i load another image and onClick on the image i have to go to another activity.

Now the problem is that when i try to fling/swipe on the imageView its onClick is called so fling() is not executed. How to resolve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Rather use the `onTouchEvent` in the `GestureDetector` class to do the work of your `onClick` method. You can use the `MotionEvent` actions to determine if it was a click or not.

Comment: how can i be sure if the touch is made on the imageView or some other view itself. I will try and get bk

Comment: What do you what me to do? write the onItemClick()'s body in onTouchEvent()? I tried that and the result is same as the touch occurs there itself the next activity is launched and fling is not detected

Comment: Thank you for the lead I figured a way out.

Answer (score 0):

you can give onClick() to all other views do nothing in them. Now in onSingleTapUp() write the imageView's onClick() body